# How do I play D&D Adventurers League adventures at home?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league

I was at a local convention this past weekend (Gary Con) and had an opportunity to play some 5E Adventurer's League.  It was my first exposure to 5E as I haven't played since v3.5.  That said, I was a huge RPGA player and have played a little PathFinder so I'm familiar with Organized Play to some extent.

I was told at the convention that you can play these Adventurers League adventures at home but the site isn't too clear on this.  I was able to find some [old postings](http://dndadventurersleague.org/faqs/will-dd-adventurers-league-adventures-be-available-for-home-play/) that indicated they'd be available with new releases.  Does this mean I am just buying the module at a store and then referring to the supplemental material online for character creation?  I assume there are certificates like existed with RPGA but I haven't seen these.  Are they provided with the purchased modules?

My confusion stems from the fact that I was told we could download modules from their site and use them at home.  I have not been able to find these.
Thanks for helping an old DM get reacquainted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The article [D&D Adventurers League Content Open To All](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/news/dd-adventurers-league-content-open-all) announced where and when they are releasing Adventurer's League content to everyone, not just organized play.

From the above link:

> We also listened to the D&D fans who wanted more bite-sized adventures
>   to pick up and play with their group in a pinch. All of the adventures
>   created for the D&D Adventurers League going forward will be available
>   to all fans of D&D. The Dungeon Masters Guild is now the hub for
>   distributing D&D Adventurers League content. You can download PDFs of
>   the adventures released periodically for a just a few dollars. Check
>   out what’s available right now from previous Adventurer’s League
>   seasons at dungeonmasterguild.com.

You can purchase previous content at the [Dungeon Masters Guild website](http://www.dmsguild.com/).

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks for the update.  It's exactly what I was hoping to hear.  I wasn't aware of the DM website either so I've downloaded what I need there.

Answer (score 3):

As well as having all previous Adventurers League content available to buy from the [Dungeon Masters Guild](http://dungeonmastersguild.com/), there have been a few released for free through the [Dragon+](http://www.dragonmag.com/) online magazine.

- DDEX3-1 Harried in Hillsfar in [Issue 3](http://www.dragonmag.com/5.0/#!/article/106372/100847778?loadFresh=true&title=03_18_Adventurer's%20League)
- DDEX3-2 Shackles of Blood in [Issue 4](http://www.dragonmag.com/5.0/#!/article/106371/100847758?loadFresh=true&title=04_22_Adventurer's%20League)
- DDEX3-3 The Occupation of Szith Morcane in [Issue 5](http://www.dragonmag.com/5.0/#!/article/106532/100901954?loadFresh=true&title=05_18_Tavern%20Tales%3A%20D%26D%20Adventurers%20League)

As far as certificates and official recognition of home play, I'm not sure. I know the Beginners Box adventure can be used for AL advancement, but I am unsure about any others. Before this recent release of AL content to all, it was a condition that AL play be done in a public forum (eg store, convention, online).

Comment: This was very useful in that I didn't know about the Dragon+ magazine and have downloaded the app and issues.  Thanks for the information.